# python numpy list convert to flask jsonify failed

Tags: python, json, list, numpy, flask

I use flask and it is so such:

global eventlist

```
NWEVENT = numpy.dtype({'names': ['call_event', 'ext_id', 'visitor_id','vfrom', 'to', 'caller_id', 'duration','create_time'],
                            'formats': ['S20','S20','S20','S20','S20','S20', 'i','S30']}, align = True)
```

and append any data into eventlist,then I want send eventlist to called:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/events', methods=['GET'])
@auth.login_required
def get_events():
    return jsonify({'call_events':eventlist.tolist()})
```

when the eventlist is zero,and it return:

```
 curl -u ok:python -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://192.168.1.140:9033/api/v1.0/events
HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 23
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.8
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 08:18:13 GMT

{
  "call_events": []
}
```

but when it has any data,it return:

```
  curl -u ok:python -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://192.168.1.140:9033/api/v1.0/events
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.8
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 08:18:13 GMT

{
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 291
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.8
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 08:48:46 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

this use :

```
 mylist = []
    #print jsonify({'call_events':eventlist})
    for event in eventlist:
        myevent = {
            'call_event':event['call_event'][0],
            'ext_id':event['ext_id'][0],
            'visitor_id':event['visitor_id'][0],
            'vfrom':event['vfrom'][0],
            'to':event['to'][0],
            'caller_id':event['caller_id'][0],
            'duration':event['duration'][0]
        }
        mylist.append(myevent)
```

Comment: That error presumably occurs while trying to `jsonify` your numpy event data - which is not JSON serializable (at least not "out of the box").